# Rails 5.2 can not pagination with kaminari and notifications

Tags: notifications, ruby-on-rails-5, kaminari

**Some of my gemfiles :**

```
gem 'rails', '~> 5.2'
gem 'notifications', '~> 0.6.0'
gem 'kaminari'
```

**My `notifications_controller.rb` like this:**

```
# notifications_controller.rb

module Notifications
  class NotificationsController < Notifications::ApplicationController
    def index
      @notifications = notifications.includes(:actor).order("id desc").page(params[:page])
      unread_ids = @notifications.reject(&:read?).select(&:id)
      Notification.read!(unread_ids)
      @notification_groups = @notifications.group_by { |note| note.created_at.to_date }
    end

    def clean
      notifications.delete_all
      redirect_to notifications_path
    end

    private

    def notifications
      raise "You need reqiure user login for /notifications page." unless current_user
      Notification.where(user_id: current_user.id)
    end
  end
end
```

**My `routes.rb` about notifications like this :**

```
mount Notifications::Engine, at: "notifications"
```

**My `index.html` about notifications like this:**

```
# notifications/notifications/index.html.erb

<div class="paginationBox">
   <%= paginate @notifications,left:2,right:1,window: 1 %>
</div>
```

**With the above codes ,  I can get the right notifications , but I can not paging the all notifications. I had the error like this:**

```
NoMethodError - undefined method `total_pages' for #<Notification::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x00007fcfacae6dd8>:
  app/views/notifications/notifications/index.html.erb:33:in `_app_views_notifications_notifications_index_html_erb__2430601159943313679_70264929101860'
```

**If I change**  the action `index` of `notifications_controller.rb`to

`@notifications = notifications.includes(:actor).order("id desc").page(params[:page]).per(10)`

**I get the same error undefined method `total_pages`....**

**If I just change** the `index.html.erb` of notificaitons to

```
<div class="paginationBox">
    <%= paginate@notifications.page(params[:page]).per(10),left:2,right:1,window: 1 %>
 </div>
```

It does not display any errors ,but the `kaminari` can not paging the all notifications .

So ,where did I had the errors? Could you please help me ? Thanks so much!

Comment: Which db are you using at the backend?

Comment: Do you have notifications record in your database or not?

Comment: I used `Mysql`, and I can get the `notifications` record in my database.But now I just can not paging the `total_pages` in notifications `index.html.erb`. Thanks @Abid lqbal...

Comment: Was it due to no notification record in the database?